# Pass a robot variable by reference to a python function

Tags: python, frameworks, robotframework

I use my own python function in Robot Framework. I give 3 parameters, these parameters are Robot Framework variables. When I modify the variables in my function, it is not modified in Robot Framework. So I deduce the variables are passed by value and not by reference... Is there a way to pass the variable by reference ? Or else to return the 3 variables as a result ?

Here is an example of Robot Framework code :

```
** Settings ***
 Library    OperatingSystem
 Library    myLib.MyLib    WITH NAME    MyLib

 Suite TearDown  teardown
 ** Variables **
 ${var}  azerty

 ** Test Cases **
 My test case
         log     ${var}
         myFunction    ${var}
         log     ${var}
```

With my python library :

```
import sys

 class MyLib(object):
     def __init__(self):
         return

     def myFunction(self,var):
         var="another value"
```

But as I said, the variable var remains "azerty" when I log it, and I would like the second log to print "another value" (as the function should change the value)

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 3):

All values are essentially passed by reference. If you change the value, you change it everywhere, but if you assign a different value to the variable, you're just making that variable point at a different value, not changing the original value.

For example:

```
def foo(d):
    d['bar'] = 'baz'
my_dict = {}
foo(my_dict)
```

Here, `my_dict` will be altered as a side effect of calling `foo(my_dict)`.

However:

```
def foo(d):
    d = {'foo': 'bar'}
my_dict = {}
foo(my_dict)
```

Here, `my_dict` isn't changed. `d` is a local variable inside `foo`, and it's changed to point to a new dictionary instead of `my_dict`.

You also need to be aware that in python, you have *mutable* and *immutable* values. Strings, for example, are *immutable*. You'll never be able to change a string, you can only use a string to construct new strings (and often you'll assign these new values back to the same variable so it'll have a similar effect); having a side effect of a function be changing one of the values that's passed in can only work if they are mutable values.

It is generally a bad idea for your functions to change their arguments though. A better approach, is to have them return new values, which the caller can then do what they want with.

```
def myFunction(self, var):
    var = "another value" # I assume that another values is based somehow on the original
    return var
```

Alternatively, you could use attributes on your class:

```
class MyLib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "initial value"
    def myFunction(self):
        self.var = "another value"
```

Comment: To summarize, do like Spoonmeiser suggests and add `return var` to `myFunction` and change your RF code to reassign `${var} =  myFunction ...`

Answer (score 0):

The var in your python code is an local variable.

```
import sys

class MyLib(object):
   def __init__(self):
       return

   def myFunction(self,var):
       var="another value"
```

This gives a variable in the myfunction  scope the name var and prevents the global variable from being read.
if you want a function to change a global variable you need to declare it a global variable in the scope.
like this:

```
import sys

class MyLib(object):
   def __init__(self):
       return

   def myFunction(self,var):
       global var
       var="another value"
```

This should change the global variable into the another value string.

Comment: Ok I understand, but how can it be done in the Robot Framework code ?

Comment: you don't need to change the Robot Framework code if you follow Headhunter's advice, use your existing robot framework code but change your python code.